# Border on an iframe? Not in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, iframe, border

It seems logical that if you want a 1px wide black border around an iframe, you apply same rule as if you want the border around anything else. But this code doesn't work:

```
#myiframe{
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

The border goes on the left and top of the iframe, sometimes (unpredictably) the bottom of it, but never the right of it. Why would it not just apply it consistently around the iframe??

I only have this problem in Google Chrome.

Comment: Long shot... tried `#000`?

Comment: @DannyBeckett no luck sorry. @user1428716 I **want** a border. `frameborder="0"` gets rid of the border. Besides, it's deprecated and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Works perfectly fine : http://jsfiddle.net/aCKyX/9/

Comment: Added link to question

Comment: The fiddle from @user1428716 works fine for me, even without `frameborder="1"`. @DuncanNZ, your link looks like a not-link? What does the `iframe` look like to you in the fiddle?

Comment: Yes the iframe looks fine in the fiddle, even without frameborder=1. Please change the underscores to dots in the link, thanks.

Comment: ... Apparently it's been a long day, didn't see the `_` to `.` conversion :/

Comment: Interesting, with your `border: 1px solid #666666;` active on the `iframe`, I see a consistent border around the `iframe`. However, if I disable that rule with the dev tools, I see what appears to be a default inset border rule applied by Chrome only on the top and left. Look at the computed styles on the iframe with your border rule disabled to see (expand the rules there to see the source of the rule). If you disable your border rule, but then set `border-style: solid` to override Chrome's default of `inset`, it renders on all four sides. Do you see the same behavior? I'm on Chrome 25.

Comment: Yes I do, but it's thinner on the right. The same happens with my border rule - if I make it `2px` it becomes only 1px wide on the right. It seems one pixel is being removed. Of course a workaround would be `border-right-width:2px;` but then goodbye Firefox...

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing the issue. For me, your custom border rule is 1px all the way around, and there doesn't seem to be any foul play from margins/width/position/etc. that I see. What version of Chrome are you on? I know it sounds like a silly question with background updates, but you never know. Also what OS? I use ArchLinux with Gnome3 at work, and I sometimes see some small weirdnesses in site layouts that are fine in, say, Windows 7. If you have another computer on hand, you might see how the site looks in Chrome on that.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Chrome 22 beta. I'll check the Windows 7 computer now.

Comment: @PerfectDark it's not parsed as 96 pixels - it's displaying just how I want it to. I didn't realise that percentage heights were deprecated - that seems weird. Do you have a link to the spec that deprecates it?

Comment: OK I can confirm there is no problem on Windows. So I will dismiss it as a browser bug that the everyday visitor won't see. Thanks for your help @ajp15243

Comment: @PerfectDark That is for the `width` attribute set directly on the `iframe`, not for the CSS style rule which is still allowed to have percentages as per the W3C wiki: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/width.

Comment: @DuncanNZ You're welcome! I would recommend getting an updated, non-beta version of Chrome now lol. They've definitely added some of the cool features that 22 Beta had by this point!

Comment: @PerfectDark no your answer doesn't seem to make a difference for me. But since I'm on Linux, and I can't reproduce on Windows, I've decided to not try to fix what seems to be a browser bug (not a bug in my CSS).

Comment: I've updated to Chrome Stable 25 (I was behind!) and now it works as expected! Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments on the question, I was on an out-of-date Chrome version. On the latest stable version, there is no bug.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this..

```
appearance:none;
-moz-appearance:none;
-webkit-appearance:none;
outline:none;
```

`outline:none` and `appearance:none` will delete default browser appearance.

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap a `DIV`

html

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <myiframe>

</div>
```

css

```
.wrapper {
float:left;
border:1px solid #000;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can get unique border around our iFrame, by using attribute frameBorder.
So try `<iframe src="" frameBorder="1"/>`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12323944)

Comment: Yes Sir agreed. Questioner wants to apply a uniform border around his iframe,  which can be done by adding the attribute frameBorder="1"